# What does Rails Builder do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the rails [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html), it gives an example of using "builder" to render inline. What is this builder and what does it do? Is it some type of gem that allows you build inline xml instead of the usual erb?

```
render inline: "xml.p {'Horrid coding practice!'}", type: :builder
```

Comment: https://github.com/jimweirich/builder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Builder](https://github.com/jimweirich/builder) gem is a dependency of the rails ActionView component. It provides a simple way to programatically build XML documents and fragments.

In Rails it is used for XML serialization in both ActiveSupport (for hashes) and ActiveModel.

> Is it some type of gem that allows you build inline xml instead of the usual erb?

The primary use of builder is not creating inline XML - that just a feature that no one really uses. Instead it can be used to build your own serializers or alter how a your models are serialized.

The comments in the source for [ActiveRecord::Serialzers::XmlSerializer](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f61d9755964af3c1812e75238e34b53ffb1f0b6a/activerecord/lib/active_record/serializers/xml_serializer.rb) explain this usage pretty well:

```
# Alternatively, you can yield the builder object as part of the to_xml call:
firm.to_xml do |xml|
  xml.creator do
    xml.first_name "David"
    xml.last_name "Heinemeier Hansson"
  end
end
```

You can contrast this with ERB which is good for building templates but not so good for building reusable components or dealing with data structures.

Comment: I would not be surprised if XML serialization is removed from the rails core in the near future. XML params parsing was delegated to an external gem and its a feature that is used less and less since JSON has pretty much won the war.

Comment: Thanks! What does it mean for a model to be serialized (or anything to be serialized)?  My understanding is that it's something that is done automatically by Rails when you save objects to the DB so that it can find it again thru AR when you retrieve it?

Comment: Serialization means converting data into another format - such as JSON or XML. This can be either hashes or complete models (or a collection of models). There is also attribute serialization - which is what you are talking about. Its where you store data such as hashes in a single text database column by converting it to YAML or JSON. However this is not used as often today as Postgres and MySQL have native JSON type columns that allow querying.